# OOP - Form holds class instance or class holds form instance?

Tags: oop, user-interface

What is the best (read: most technically correct) way to handle GUI's for class objects?

Say, for example, that I have a class to deal with I/O. Let's call it `clsIO`. I also have a form to allow the user to change various options/properties of this class, let's call it `frmIO`. The `frmIO` GUI is specific to the `clsIO`, it will not be used anywhere else in the application.

My application will always create an instance of the `clsIO`, it will load its default settings and begin its operation. The user may or may not need to show the `frmIO` 'settings form' so that he can configure it.

To me, it appears that the best way to handle this is to store an object reference to the form inside the class, and provide a `ShowConfigForm()` method, rather than instantiate the form, which in turn instantiates the class.

Is this sound design?

EDIT

I plan to reuse this class/form combo across multiple projects. I have already developed it in its own project, so i can easily transfer/import to other projects that may require it.

Simple pseudo code with my current design:

```
class clsIO
{
  public bool Active{get;set;}
  public int Port{get;set;}
  public ShowConfigForm()
  {
    frmIO settings = new frmIO(this);
    settings.Show();
  }
}

class frmIO
{
  private clsIO _IO;
  public frmIO(clsIO IO){_IO = IO;};//constructor
  private btnEnable_Click()
  {
     _IO.Active = true;
    //etc etc
  }
}
```

Here I only need to instantiate the `clsIO`. Not the other way around.

Comment: The question is a bit vague, but it seems to me that you have an *application* that is responsible for making all those classes work together, and it should have instances of the I/O class and the GUI class.

Comment: You are correct, say a winforms application, but generally I would design a 'Managing' class which controls interaction between various classes (`clsIO` and others). This way, the 'managing' class needs only worry about the class objects rather than the GUI. In this particular example, the GUI is always tied to the class, but each one (`clsIO` and `frmIO`) is dependent on each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've done, there's a  tight coupling from clsIO  to the frmIO ( which is the GUI class). This is not a good practice as this tight coupling will stop you form doing Unit Testing etc.. also in case you need clsIO to be re-used for some other operation, this tight coupling to fromIO stops you from doing so.

There need to be another class that puts them together by first instantiating the clsIO and then frmIO by passing the clsIO instance into frmIO.
This way you separate the concerns of each class and give the responsibility of wiring thins up to another one, which would be cleaner.

Furthermore you can improve the design by extracting an interface from clsIO class and using the interface type within the frmIO to refer to clsIO. this will help you to have a loose coupling bewteen the 2 classes.

let me know if you me to provide a code sample, if what I described doesnt make much sense.

Comment: +1 thanks I can see it better now. In reality my `clsIO` does actually implement an interface too.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would have a class containing the configuration. The form itself has a reference to that `settings` class. If the user changes a setting in the form, the form tells it to the `settings` class/object.

Now you can register your `clsIO` as an observer on the settings. Meaning whenever something changes, the `clsIO` gets notified and can update its operations (this way around, the settings would contain references to all of its observers). This is known as the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Has its strength if many 'unknown' objects observe something. I mean, settings may be something, which would impact on many different classes/objects. The observers only decide on the settings, but never change them.

If you want to keep it simple, without much effort, just add a reference to the settings in your `clsIO`. It's a design you can choose. This one is simpler, so if its a small and simple application, it should be sufficient.

But what I think you should really do is, separate the form from the values. A form is just a view, while the actual values are contained in another class.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my question. My Settings class is `clsIO`, and indeed the form notifies any changes via the GUI directly to the `clsIO`. I cannot see why i would need **another** class to handle the interaction.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry for that. I read the updated question again. So basically your clsIO always exists, but frmIO is only needed if the user wants to change something. Your solution so far makes sense. You can do it this way. The most important question is then: does frmIO need access to clsIO or is it the other way around. Seems like clsIO only reads from frmIO, but frmIO does not even know about clsIO. So it seems ok to have a reference from clsIO to frmIO.